# Build fails when trying to create workspace from selected pallets and primitives

Tags: rust, build, cargo

I want to put some pallets and primitive code in a workspace. Here is my code https://github.com/zeitgeistpm/external

However this does not build, neither workspace builds nor individual components.
When building with node and runtime that works.
Getting same error in all case:

```
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~/dev/external/vrf$ cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/encointer/substrate-fixed`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus`
error: no matching package found
searched package name: `sp-core`
perhaps you meant:      sp-io or sp-trie
location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32
required by package `moonbeam-vrf v0.1.0 (/home/vivek/dev/external/vrf)`
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~/dev/external/vrf$ cd ..

vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~/dev/external$ cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/encointer/substrate-fixed`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus`
error: no matching package found
searched package name: `sp-core`
perhaps you meant:      sp-io or sp-trie
location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32
required by package `moonbeam-vrf v0.1.0 (/home/vivek/dev/external/vrf)`
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~/dev/external$ ls
Cargo.toml  nimbus-consensus  nimbus-primitives  pallets  session-keys  vrf
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~/dev/external$ cd pallets/
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~/dev/external/pallets$ ls
author-inherent  author-mapping  author-slot-filter  parachain-staking
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~/dev/external/pallets$ cd author-inherent/


vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~/dev/external/pallets/author-inherent$ cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/encointer/substrate-fixed`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus`
error: no matching package found
searched package name: `sp-core`
perhaps you meant:      sp-io or sp-trie
location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32
required by package `moonbeam-vrf v0.1.0 (/home/vivek/dev/external/vrf)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything works on my local.

```
gh repo clone zeitgeistpm/external
cd external
cargo check --workspace
```

Try switching your network ENV.

Comment: Could you please share more details here? Like what rust version using, also anything which may impact indexing or searching of packages ?

Comment: nightly version. But you failed at the searching step. I think it is not related to the compiler. I think you should check your network.